# Ido only shows directories and no files

Tags: init-file, ido

When I am using `ido`, it only shows the folders and not the files within the folders. I have the following code in the `init.el` file:

```
;;Setup ido                                                                 
(ido-mode 1)                                                                
(setq ido-find-file t)                                                      
(setq ido-everywhere t)                                                     
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)                                           
(setq ido-default-file-method 'selected-window)                             
(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)                           
(setq ido-use-filename-at-point 'guess)
```

Can't understand why this is happening. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is it showing the folders? What do you do to show them? If you are doing `C-x C-f` it may be truncating the list: are there three dots at the end? If so, there are too many completions for `ido` to show you in the echo area: you'll have to help it by giving it a bit more information, e.g. the first few letters of the file name you are looking for. Pressing `TAB` will show you a buffer with all the completions.

Comment: @NickD thank you for your answer, I did use C-x d, and that why I didn't could see all the files.

Comment: `C-x d` calls `dired`; it would be counter-productive for that command to offer non-directory completion options.  (Well... actually, you *can* enter a non-directory and get a dired buffer showing the matching files... you *probably* wouldn't want that for a specific single file, though... I think it's primarily intended to be used with glob patterns.)